# PhpStorm - change size and color of changed lines

Tags: configuration, colors, phpstorm

When editing file that is under version control in right side scroller PhpStorm have small colored info about which lines have been added, modified, deleted.

[image]
*PhpStorm version: 6.0.2*

This small info about line changes is too small for me.

How can I make it bigger or change color so I can spot it better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well ... the colors can be configured at `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`

- Added lines
- Modified lines

But the screenshot you are showing .. it looks more like Difference Viewer rather than Editor itself (since in Editor such info is shown in editor gutter area (next to line numbers) which is on the left side -- opposite side to where scrollbar is).

Therefore you may be looking for `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Diff` instead (screenshot is too small for me to tell anything more).

Comment: Thank You! Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Diff -> "Stripe mark color" is what I was looking for :)